# Get attribute from touching line layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis-3

I have two line layers. The features of both are touching each. Now I would like to label one of the line layers with the attributes of the touching layer.

The case: In the one layer are drain's (green) and in the other one are cables (red). The cables are inside the drain (digitized with snapping to the drains). Now I need the drain-id (green labels) labeled on every cable.

[image]

I have to use shape files! So I thought to use the aggregate function of QGIS...

Comment: If you're going to publish this map, please choose a different color scheme. Red + lime green is a combination that appears to vibrate on the screen. It will give most users of your map a headache, and anyone with red-green colorblindness won't be able to read it at all.

Comment: In your screenshot, the lime color object looks like a generic, i.e. as one map object, then where does it come from different green signatures?

Comment: I used symbol levels... And I will choose other color combination next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RefFunctions Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) together with this expression:

```
 geomintersects('drain','drainid')
```

'drain' is the targetlayername and 'drainid' the targetfieldname you want to get.