# Get attributes from touching lines in network - results seems random

Tags: qgis, aggregation

This question is similar to this one: [Get attribute from touching line layer (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321153/get-attribute-from-touching-line-layer-qgis) but there is a new and more komplex problem in that context I need to solve:

I have to plan drains, usually along a road network or any existing network digitized with snapping and tracing.  In in that drains will be cables. The cables will also be digitized with tracing and end in every drain junction. No cables cross a junction. There could be up to 10 cables inside one drain. The drains are identified by ID's.

Every cable need a (virtual)field with the ID of the drain in which it lies. With the refFunctions solution:

```
(geomintersects('drain','drainid')
```

from the question linked above, I will get the drain ID for every cable, BUT the cables are also touching other drains at their end/start nodes if there is a junction. The results will become something like random! If the drains are not touching at their junctions (digitizing a small gab), the expression will work fine. But that is not a well suiting solution for me.

You can reproduce the situation with the following [package](https://www.map-site.de/tmp/drainsandcables.gpkg):

[image]

Comment: I may be mistaken, but at first glance it would be better for you to move away from the symbolization of the pipe to the actualization, i.e. really try to model your situation, for example, show the pipe in the form of a polygon with a real width, and cables in the form of lines by their number, with their identifiers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, if the *refFunctions* plugin defines the spatial relation predicates as per the OGC standard, `contains` or `overlaps` should work, if your geometries are as precise as you describe. In your example data-set however, the cables extent out of the drains so that where `contains` fails, `within` succeeds. And in the reality of floating point numbers, both `contains` and `within` are tricky with entities like lines, but `overlaps`, or `crosses` even, might catch them.

So just check them all:

```
COALESCE( geomwithin( 'drains', 'ID' ),  geomcontains( 'drains', 'ID' ),  geomoverlaps( 'drains', 'ID' ),  geomcrosses( 'drains', 'ID' ))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your pipes from lines to polygons as [Cyril](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/120129/cyril) suggested, the solution becomes simple. Now it doesn't matter that a cable *intersects* multiple pipe polygons, because it's only *within* the one corresponding pipe polygon. Use `geomwithin()` instead of `geomintersects()` in the expression you already wrote.

Comment: I also thought about going that way, but for several reasons, I cant convert the lines to polygons. I also thought about doing it temporary inside an expression like: geomwithhin(buffer(geometry,1)) - but that seems not to be possible with refFunctions

Comment: No, the RefFunctions are user-friendly but limited in scope. You'll need to graduate to the more complicated `aggregate` functions. Try something like `aggregate( 'drain', 'array_agg',"drainid",intersects($geometry,buffer(geometry(@parent),1)))` or possibly `aggregate( 'drain', 'array_agg',"drainid",intersects(buffer($geometry,1),geometry(@parent)))`.

Comment: Both functions results in NULL... what does that 'array_agg' mean?

Comment: Array_agg is one of the aggregate functions. Have a look at the Expression Builder help section about the `aggregate()` function, and the section about the `array_agg()` function. Basically, `aggregate('layer name', 'array_agg', ...)' means, "run the `array_agg` function on features in the layer called 'layer name' "

Comment: here's a good blog post about how the aggregate functions work: https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/08/aggregate-all-the-things-qgis-expression-edition/